# Android ListView FooterView width not mach parent

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview for display message, and I wanna add footerview to show loadmore button, if the listview set `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` it works normally, but I need to give it an absolute value to set listview height such as `android:layout_height="400dip"` so as to avoid getview method repeat calling , and then the footerview width can’t match parent.

Answer (score 1):

Set the list view `layout_height="fill_parent"` and `layout_weight="1"`, then anything that you put under it will have space.